# WCF Webservice and Silverlight with compression

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf

My application consists of a WCF web service and a silverlight client. I need to transfer data on the order of GBs. Is it possible to send compressed data so that it can be uncompressed by the client when it is received? What classes can I make use for this?

Answer (score 2):

I never had to use it but maybe you should take a look at [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Download.aspx) (An open source dll for compression)

Here's also 3 links about WCF compression:

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2008/11/06/wcf-and-http-gzip-deflate-compression-and-silverlight.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/03/29/441398.aspx

http://frenk.wordpress.com/2009/11/08/gzip-compression-between-wcf-web-service-and-silverlight/

Comment: Isn't there a .NET API for this?